# Javascript disabled button does not gets enabled when the form is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, disable

I have a form and I wanted to disable the submit button unless the required fields are filled.

So I added this:

```
$('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', true);

if ($('#inputMobile').val() != '' && $('#inputEmail').val() != '' && $('#inputPassword').val() != '' && $('#inputPasswordConfirmation').val() != '') {
      $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Now it works fine and disable the submit button when the page loads but when I fill in the form fields, it does not enable the button however I tried setting the `disabled` attr to `false`.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your test runs when the page loads, before the user has typed anything. You need to add an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to addListener on form?
Also you could check solution in similar question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67961881/19282017

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs once, when the page is loaded, you need action after the user enters data. Use a change event.

You need a way to specify the event on all 4 fields, so give your four input fields a common class, for example registerInput.

```
<input type="text" class="registerInput">
```

Do that for all 4 of your fields.

Then specify a change event, selecting that class, so that your test is run every time the user changes one of the fields.

```
$(".registerInput").change(function() {
  if ($('#inputMobile').val() != '' 
      && $('#inputEmail').val() != '' 
      && $('#inputPassword').val() != '' 
      && $('#inputPasswordConfirmation').val() != '') {
        $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With this dummy code, I just wanted to show that your code for changing the attribute is completely true. It seems your code doesn't meet the condition in the `if` statement.

```js
$('#but2').attr('disabled',true)

$('#but1').on('click',() => {
  if(true){
    $('#but2').attr('disabled',!$('#but2').attr('disabled'))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="but1">Toggle</button>
<button id="but2">Change me</button>
```